# ACE how to enable IPv6

Tags: c++, linux, ipv6, ace

I am using ACE v5.7.1 in linux.
I want to enable ipv6 so that my server can accept ipv6 requests also.i have added #define ACE_HAS_IPV6 in the ace/config.h file.But still the return value from the method ACE_ipv6_enabled() is 0

when i create a simple client with ACE_INET_Addr(port,ipv6_address) and trying to connect the server it is giving error ACE_INET_Addr :: permission denied

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the Incorrect constructor for this.  Take a look at this link:

http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.1/html/ace/a00246.html#0ef39cee9fc65be37ca6ce4092b6ea04

You will need to call it similar to the following:

```
ACE_INET_Addr(port, <hostname e.g. "localhost6">, AF_INET6);
```

By default you have `AF_UNSPEC` which will probably assume `AF_INET`

Comment: i have added AF_INET6 in the ACE_INET_Addr(). but still my client gives error ACE_INET_Addr::ACE_INET_Addr: [::1] : operation not permitted

Comment: @smitajit Can you post your constructor call?

Comment: ACE_INET_Addr my_addr(5056,[::1],AF_INET6).the value returned from ACE::ipv6_enabled() is 0.

Comment: @smitajit Has ACE been compiled with ACE_HAS_IPV6?

Comment: @smitajit What happens when you try to ping6 the same address?

Comment: @smitajit I've amended the answer.  For reason as yet unknown the system doesn't like "::1" in the constructor but "localhost6" works.

Comment: @smitajit  By the looks of things you have edited 'config.h' after compile and not compile ACE with configuration of '--enable-ipv6'